# Why can't we define $\liminf$ as $\liminf_nA_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I know that $\liminf$ is defined as

$\liminf_nA_n=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k.$

I understand that it means that it is a member of all but finitely many of $A_n$.

My question is why don't we then define it as

$\liminf_nA_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k.$

Are the two definitions the same? I am unable to spot the difference. Please help.

Comment: That would be the intersection of all the sets..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$ B_n = \bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k. $$
Then $B_1$ consists of every element that belongs to all of $A_1,A_2,\dots$. $B_2$ consists of every element that belongs to all of $A_1,A_2,\dots$ except possibly not to $A_1$. $B_3$ consists of everything that belongs to $A_1, A_2, \dots$ except possibly not to $A_1$ or $A_2$. Therefore

$$\bigcup_n B_n = \liminf A_n $$

consists of everything that belongs to all of $A_1,A_2,\dots$ except possibly not to finitely many of them. The key phrase is "all but finitely many."

On the other hand,

$$ \bigcap_n B_n = \bigcap_n A_n $$

is the set of everything that belongs to all of $A_1,A_2,\dots$.

For example, let $A_1 = \{1\}$ and $A_2 = A_3 = A_4 = \dots = \{1, 2\}$. Then $B_1 = \{1\}$ and $B_2 = B_3 = B_4 = \dots = \{1,2\}$. So

$$ \bigcap_n B_n = \bigcap_n A_n = \{1\} $$

because only $1$ belongs to all of $A_1,A_2,\dots$. But

$$ \bigcup_n B_n = \{1,2\} $$

because $1$ belongs to all of $A_1,A_2,\dots$ and $2$ belongs to all but finitely many of $A_1,A_2,\dots$ (all but $A_1$).

Comment: Does that mean $\liminf \{A_n\}$ where $A_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ is the set of natural numbers?

Comment: @pavybez It does.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A_0=\varnothing$. Then $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k=\varnothing$, **regardless** of the values of the other $A_n$! That's bad. This extreme sensitivity to the first set in the sequence is the opposite of what we want from a limit operator.

A good limit definition should not depend at all on $A_0$. (For that matter, it should not depend on $A_1$, and it should not depend on $A_2$...)

Answer (score 1):

Take $A_n = \{-n,-(n-1),-(n-2),...\}$. Then the first definition gives the integers, but the second definition gives the natural numbers. So they are different.

Comment: I understand how the second definition gives natural numbers but I am not yet fully convinced that the first definition gives integers. I need to reflect on it a bit to be able to prove it.

Comment: The idea is this: Pick any negative number. Then it is not a member of the first few A's but is a member of all subsequent ones. The first definition says that one may take the union of all intersections that neglect the first few A's, so our negative number is eventually included. Feel free to come back with more questions.

Comment: Going by the same logic, if I pick any negative number, and take the intersection of all intersections that neglect the first few A's, our negative number is eventually included?

Comment: The difference is that the intersection is unfriendly to this kind of inclusion. The second definition would kick out the negative number permanently as soon as it finds a set that does not have it. The union keeps searching until it finds a set that does include it.

Comment: I follow now but the other explanation by Trevor was far more easier to understand.